# я хочу отследить какой скрипт был запущен в моем package.json но process.env.npm_lifecycle_event равняеться undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, package.json

Хочу отследить какой скрипт был запущен в моем  react-native приложении
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но получаю undefined
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как можно решить данную проблему, или же как еще можно отследить запускаемый скрипт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от платформы, есть несколько уже готовых решений на Stackoverflow:

- для [Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json#answer-27090755) платформ (смотрите также под комментариями как решался этот вопрос под Windows)
- для [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows) платформ